# I have tried this code for getting current location in google maps API but there is no errors and code is not working

Tags: android

code seems to be not working there r no errors in the activity all it shows is a blank map and also get location button is not working

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality() + ",";
                        str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            });

        } else {
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                        try {
                            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                            String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality() + ",";
                            str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                    }
                });
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        // LatLng Location = new LatLng(12.977827, 77.570706);
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location).title("bangalore"));
        // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Location, 10.2f));
    }

}
```

Comment: have you requested the permissions? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Have added location permission in manifest

Comment: You need to update in same code or would you need to have new code which is working

Comment: all permission r given

Comment: yes, i would like a working code

Comment: can u please share the working code